# ¿Como crear una petición POST con un REST Template?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Estoy probando de crear una peticion POST para un REST Template.

Entonces tengo el siguiente código , cómo parámetro recibe un String en formato Json.

```
public String post(String uri, String json) {
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(json, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = rest.exchange(server + uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        this.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

Yo se lo envío de la siguiente forma

```
for(int i=0;i<url.size();i++) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            restClient.post("/insertarURL", gson.toJson(url.get(i)));
        }
```

Porqué se envía como nulo ?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a tú pregunta el código que tienes relacionado con la variable headers y la variable rest?

Comment: @jc1992 cual es el problema?? para la petición solo agrega la anotación `@POST`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está al enviar un JSON como body.

Intenta convertir tu JSON a un Object (genérico o personalizado) y pasárselo como body al HttpEntity.

Puedes usar el método `readValue(jsonString, Object)` de `ObjectMapper` para hacerlo.